# Script shell get id and kill process

Tags: shell-script, awk

Please, i can't find the error in my command.

```
ssh -t root@$machine -x "sshpass -p 'ubuntu' ssh -t root@$address -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/nul -x 'ps -ef | grep "myprocess" | awk {print $2} | xargs kill'"
```

I have this error:

```
awk: line 2: missing } near end of file
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: awk format is different. Instead of awk {print $2}  use awk '{print $2}'. You need to refactor your code

Comment: @RomeoNinov That won't work directly, because OP is already using `''` to quote the `ps -ef` and pipes command.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling,yes, but awk will not work (in above example) also. So as I mention he/she should rewrite the code :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov: same error "awk: line 2: missing } near end of file"

Comment: @researcher  check above comments and replace awk with cut for example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65932/how-to-get-the-first-word-of-a-string

Comment: What about using `pkill`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problems, it's usually best to start by **breaking it into its constituent parts.** Start with the innermost expression, which seems to aim to get all PIDs for `myprocess` in order to signal them, and work your way outwards, testing each step along the way to make sure it gives the output you expect.

You are doing this by taking the output of `ps`, grepping for the process, running the output through `awk` to extract the relevant PID, then passing that to xargs. By looking at what you are actually *trying to accomplish* rather than the specific problem you're facing, I can tell that **there are at least two much better ways to do this,** which also coincidentally totally avoid the problem you are facing (which is based on having a number of layers of quoting within a single compound command).

---

One is to keep the `ps` and use its `-C` and `-o` parameters to get only the information you are interested in. This is actually mentioned as an example in the ps(1) man page. You would then want:

```
ps -C myprocess -o pid=
```

which will print only the PID(s) of any processes with the image name `myprocess`. This can then trivially be piped into xargs, replacing your `ps ... | xargs kill` with:

```
ps -C myprocess -o pid= | xargs kill
```

or possibly using process substitution to avoid the pipe and xargs entirely:

```
kill $( ps -C myprocess -o pid= )
```

---

The **even better alternative** is to use `killall` to signal all processes with a given image name directly:

```
killall -e myprocess
```

Here, `-e` specifies "exact" mode, in which process image names much match exactly. In this case, replace your `ps ... | xargs kill` entirely with the above.

---

> `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/nul`

Oh, and the conventional name is /dev/null, not /dev/nul. `NUL` is CP/M-ism from the mid-1970s, carried forward by Microsoft into current versions of Windows. In this particular case, the effect may or may not be the same, depending on how strict your `ssh` is.